# Invoke Soap Service Using Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to create a proxy service to call an external Soap service using wso2 proxy service.

I have created a proxy service like this:

```
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <property name="messageType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence>
        <log level="full">
            <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default &quot;fault&quot; sequence"/>
            <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
            <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
        </log>
        <log level="custom">
            <property name="Trace" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
        </log>
    </faultSequence>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit"/>
    </endpoint>
</target>
```

Please have a look into this link (http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit)

I want to call this Soap Service using a proxy service.

I am using REST Client (Mozilla Firefox Addon) and

My Input Request:

```
<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
 <Celsius>33</Celsius>
</CelsiusToFahrenheit>
```

I am getting an error while calling this service using a proxy service.

Below is my error. I have enabled TRACE on my proxy service configuration.

```
[2014-03-17 11:42:16,187]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.FilterMediatorProxy} -  Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2014-03-17 11:42:16,188]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.FilterMediatorProxy} -  ERROR_CODE : 0 ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out
[2014-03-17 11:42:16,188]  INFO {SERVICE_LOGGER.FilterMediatorProxy} -  FaultHandler executing impl: org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler
[2014-03-17 11:42:16,189]  WARN {SERVICE_LOGGER.FilterMediatorProxy} -  Executing fault sequence mediator : org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator
[2014-03-17 11:42:16,194]  INFO {SERVICE_LOGGER.FilterMediatorProxy} -  To: http://10.132.97.131:9763/services/FilterMediatorProxy.FilterMediatorProxyHttpEndpoint/, From: 10.132.97.131, Direction: request, MESSAGE = Executing default "fault" sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Unexpected error during sending message out, Envelope: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>
<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
   <Celsius>33</Celsius>
</CelsiusToFahrenheit></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2014-03-17 11:42:16,206]  INFO {SERVICE_LOGGER.FilterMediatorProxy} -  
Trace = org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unexpected error during sending message out
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.handleException(Axis2Sender.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send   (Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:338)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:333)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:187)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterServletAdaptor.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mashup.jsservices.custom.ui.CustomUIServletFilter.doFilter(CustomUIServletFilter.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.FilterServletAdaptor.service(FilterServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:197)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:185)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:482)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:59)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:622)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
    ... 53 more
```

What's wrong in my configuration? While I am directly calling the Soap service (without using any proxy from REST client), I am getting the response correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You must send the request to the back-end service,
in following proxy, in inSequence it sends the request to the back-end service and the response of the back-end service is sent back to the client in outSequence by the `<send/>`

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="CelsiusToFahrenheitService"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I tested the above proxy using the `Try this service` in ESB,

Request is,

```
<body>
 <CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
   <Celsius>88</Celsius>
 </CelsiusToFahrenheit>    
</body>
```

And I got the following response,

```
<CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
   <CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>190.4</CelsiusToFahrenheitResult>
</CelsiusToFahrenheitResponse>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,, I have tried ur service with `Try this service`, but still i am getting the same error... `ERROR_CODE : 0 ERROR_MESSAGE : Unexpected error during sending message out` Shall i need to do any other configuration.. I am using ** wso2-carbon 4.2.0 and i have installed ESB 4.8.0 into it**.

Comment: Did you add this Send mediator in your porxy?

`<send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>`

Use the proxy that I added earlier and try

Comment: Yes sir,, I have configured the same proxy what u given above,i am getting error only.. I printed the trace,it's showing `Connection Refused`

Comment: I have tried  the above proxy configuration directly using **WSO2ESB 4.0.3**,i am not able to get the Response.,getting TIMEOUT Exception.. Which ESB u r using?? Have you done any other configuration?? Please help me on this

Comment: No configurations needed. I just add the above proxy to fresh ESB 4.8.1 and it worked.
Just go to Services -> Add -> proxy service -> custom proxy -> switch to source view, and replace the `<proxy>.....</proxy>` with the above given proxy.
Then go to `try this service` and send the request as mentioned above. it should work.

Comment: Thanks boss,,, But what i did is exactly what u told,but not getting the Response :( Used **ESB 4.0.3** directly and tried **wso2carbon 4.2.0 and ESB 4.8.0 installed on it** and tried

Comment: Getting the following error `2014-03-17 14:20:34,007 [-] [HttpClientWorker-8]  WARN EndpointContext Endpoint : endpoint_85b04c7bca0566d6505d11b60749f8345e82a3038c208c06 will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
2014-03-17 14:20:34,008 [-] [HttpClientWorker-8]  WARN EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : endpoint_85b04c7bca0566d6505d11b60749f8345e82a3038c208c06 - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon Mar 17 14:21:04 IST 2014`

Comment: Response ==  `<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out</TryitProxyError>`

Comment: It seems like there is a firewall blocking the connection, is it?

Comment: But i am able to call this service directly without using the ProxyService!!!!,,,,

Comment: I am able to Connect an External RESTService(JSON Request and JSON Response) using a proxy service and got the response successfully... Facing issues while calling a SOAP Service!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Don't know the issue,,Anyone helpme

Comment: I have downloaded wso2esb 4.8.1 and used with ur proxy service,still i am getting the `Request Timed Out` Exception...!!!!!

Comment: I am getting the exception **Invalid Address,Unable to establish a Connection** while using the below link (**http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit**).. Then how u r getting the response successfully using the same Proxy service?????!!!!!!

Comment: yeah it seems like something is wrong with the url now.
You want to test this scenario right?
Then why don't you use the axis2Server bundle with wso2esb for this?
Build the sample https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/ESB+Samples+Setup

then start the server and access the service url in the proxy