# WSO2 ESB (4.9.0) Proxy Server Authentication

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to use Salesforce connector through proxy server at my workplace.

Configured Proxy settings followed by [Configuring PROXY settings in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475053/configuring-proxy-settings-in-wso2-esb-4-8-1) and simple api test:

[image]

It seems the Proxy credentials are not used at all from output console:

[image: outcome1]

[image: outcome2]

Could someone please give me a hint why the credentials are missing? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following configuration.

```
  <salesforce.init>
    <username>sean32@gmail.com</username>
    <password>passwordToken</password>
    <loginUrl>https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0</loginUrl>
    <forcelogin/>
  </salesforce.init>
```

Comment: It is not working because the element, <forcelogin/>, is always missing after clicking Save button. Furthermore, my problem is that the request cannot even go through proxy server of the company because the Proxy-Authorization property does not apply.

Comment: The problem is caused by my organisation firewall (Proxy server) instead of Salesforce connector.